# Dynamically added fields in cascading drop down not cloning styles and ignoring change function

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamically-generated, cascadingdropdown

I am creating 4 fields in a form for someone to select a product type. The order of the fields goes like this: Category > Type > Size > Color

If someone changes the category or type selection, all of the next fields should reset. This works fine on the first set of fields, but if someone clicks my "Add product" button, the cloned set of fields ignores the code I have written that works on the first. I don't see any error messages and I'm not sure what is going wrong.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gajSu/

And here is exactly what is not working correctly:

1. If you make a selection in the first drop down you see the corresponding product types appear.
2. If you click Add product - both fields are cloned. I want the whole UL cloned but the "display: none" style defined for the last 3 list items should not be ignored - only the product category should display, just like it does when you load it.
3. If you change the Category in the cloned drop down (2nd product), the options in the second don't reset like it does in the first one.

I hope this makes sense.  I know there are plugins that can do this but I would like to build this myself so I can learn.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**jQuery**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('div' + '.menu').hide();
        $('a').click(function () {
            $('#' + $(this).attr('class')).show().siblings('div').hide();
        });
    prods = {
    Cookware: ["- Select -", "Round French Oven", "Oval French Oven", "Braiser", "Skillet", "Fry Pan", "Grill Pan", "Saute Pan", "Saucepan", "Saucier", "Griddle", "Roaster", "Stockpot", "Speciality Cookware", "Other"],
    Bakeware: ["- Select -", "Covered Casserole", "Baking Dish", "Stoneware Gratin", "Speciality Bakeware", "Individual Bakeware", "Metal Bakeware", "Other"],
    KitchenTools: ["- Select -", "Utensils", "Kitchen Accessories", "Cutlery", "Wine Tools", "Textiles", "Other"],
    DineEntertain: ["- Select -", "Dinnerware", "Serveware", "Tabletop Accessories", "Glassware", "Kettles", "Tea Collection", "Café Collection", "Other"]
    };      
        var prodSelect = $('.prod-info');
        var category = $('select[name^="Product_category"]');
        var productType = $('select[name^="Product_type"]');
        prodSelect.change(function () {
            var catSelected = $(this).val();
            console.log(catSelected);
            $(this).parent("li").next("li.subCats").fadeIn('fast'); /*Fades in next option once selection has been made*/       
            if($(this).is(category)) {
                $('select[name^="Product_type"]').empty();  
                $('.product-size, .product-color').prop('selectedIndex',0);                 
                $.each(prods[catSelected], function (key, value) {
                    $('select[name^="Product_type"]')
                        .append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", value)
                        .attr("name", value)
                        .text(value));
                });                     
            }
            if($(this).is(productType)) {
                $('.product-size, .product-color').prop('selectedIndex',0);                                     
            } 
        });         
        var otherSelect = $('select');
        var select = this.value;
        otherSelect.change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 'Other') {
                $(this).next('.other').show();
            }
            else $(this).next('.other').hide();
        });

        $('#add-product').click(function () {
                   $('<ul/>', {
                       'class' : 'extraPerson', html: GetHtml()
             }).hide().appendTo('#container').slideDown('slow');

             });
     function GetHtml()
        {
              var len = $('.extraPerson').length;
            var $html = $('.extraPersonTemplate').clone();
            $html.find('[name=Product_category1]')[0].name="Product_category" + len;
            return $html.html();    
        }
```

});

**HTML**

```
        <form id="warranty">
            <ul class="extraPersonTemplate">
                <li>
                    <label for="Product_category">Product Category <em>*</em></label> 
                    <select name="Product_category1" class="category prod-info" style="width: 160px;">
                        <option value="">- Select Category-</option>
                        <option value="Cookware">Cookware</option>
                        <option value="Bakeware">Bakeware</option>
                        <option value="KitchenTools">Kitchen Tools</option>
                        <option value="DineEntertain">Dine & Entertain</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li style="display: none;" class="subCats">
                    <label for="Product_type">Product Type <em>*</em></label> 
                    <select name="Product_type1" class="product-type prod-info"></select>
                    <div class="other" style="display: none;">
                        <label for="Other_Product_Type">If Other, please specify: </label> 
                        <input class="text-field" name="Other_Product_Type1" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li style="display: none;" class="subCats">
                    <label for="Product_size">Product Size <em>*</em></label> 
                    <select name="Product_size1" class="product-size prod-info" style="width: auto; outline: none; width:120px;">
                        <option value="">- Select Size -</option>
                        <option value="1_QT">1 qt.</option>
                        <option value="2_QT">2 qt.</option>
                        <option value="3-half_QT">3 &frac12; qt.</option>
                        <option value="4-half_QT">4 &frac12; qt.</option>
                        <option value="5_QT">5 qt.</option>
                        <option value="5-half_QT">5 &frac12; qt.</option>
                        <option value="6-threequarter_QT">6 &frac34; qt. </option>
                        <option value="7-quarter_QT">7 &frac14; qt.</option>
                        <option value="8_QT">8 qt.</option>
                        <option value="9_QT">9 qt.</option>
                        <option value="9-half_QT">9 &frac12; qt.</option>
                        <option value="12_QT">12 qt.</option>
                        <option value="13-quarter_QT">13 &frac14; qt.</option>
                        <option value="15-half_QT">15 &frac12; qt.</option>
                        <option value="10-quarter_in">10 &frac14;&quot;</option>
                        <option value="11-threequarter_in">11 &frac34;&quot;</option>
                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                        <option value="NA">Not Applicable</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="other" style="display: none;">
                        <label for="Other_Product_Size">If Other, please specify: </label> 
                        <input class="text-field" name="Other_Product_Size1" />
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li style="display: none;" class="subCats">
                <label for="Product_color">Product Color <em>*</em></label> 
                    <select name="Product_color1" class="product-color prod-info">
                        <option value="">- Select Color -</option>
                        <option value="Amethyst">Amethyst</option>
                        <option value="Aubergine">Aubergine</option>
                        <option value="Black Onyx">Black Onyx</option>
                        <option value="Caribbean">Caribbean</option>
                        <option value="Cassis">Cassis</option>
                        <option value="Cherry">Cherry</option>
                        <option value="Cobalt">Cobalt</option>
                        <option value="Coral">Coral</option>
                        <option value="Cotton">Cotton</option>
                        <option value="Cream">Cream</option>
                        <option value="Dijon">Dijon</option>
                        <option value="Dune">Dune</option>
                        <option value="Fennel">Fennel</option>
                        <option value="Flame">Flame</option>
                        <option value="Indigo">Indigo</option>
                        <option value="Ink">Ink</option>
                        <option value="Kiwi">Kiwi</option>
                        <option value="Lapis">Lapis</option>
                        <option value="Linen">Linen</option>
                        <option value="Marseille">Marseille</option>
                        <option value="Mineral Blue">Mineral Blue</option>
                        <option value="Ocean">Ocean</option>
                        <option value="Palm">Palm</option>
                        <option value="Quince">Quince</option>
                        <option value="Rosemary">Rosemary</option>
                        <option value="Sisal">Sisal</option>
                        <option value="Soleil">Soleil</option>
                        <option value="Spinach">Spinach</option>
                        <option value="Truffle">Truffle</option>
                        <option value="White">White</option>
                        <option value="Stainless">Stainless Steel</option>
                        <option value="FHA">Non-stick</option>
                        <option value="NoColor">N/A</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
            </ul>       
            <div id="container"></div>      
            <div id="add-product">Add a product</div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve point 2 : "If you click Add product - both fields are cloned. I want the whole UL cloned but the "display: none" style defined for the last 3 list items should not be ignored - only the product category should display, just like it does when you load it."

I added at the end after  :

```
<div id="extraPersonTemplateSaveInit"></div>
```

In JS top, just after document ready :

```
$('#extraPersonTemplateSaveInit').hide();     
$(".extraPersonTemplate").clone().appendTo('#extraPersonTemplateSaveInit');
```

And GetHtml method :

```
function GetHtml()
{
    var len = $('.extraPerson').length;
    var $html = $('#extraPersonTemplateSaveInit .extraPersonTemplate').clone();
    $html.find('[name=Product_category1]')[0].name="Product_category" + len;
    return $html.html();    
}
```

But now, "change" event is no longer triggered for the second product. 
Hope this will still help. I keep searching